# Getting Java beans that were set in a try method

Tags: java, javabeans

I am setting a java bean from within a try method.  A text file is being read and the text that is read is used to set the java bean.

```
public class mainDisplay extends JPanel{



private imageDisplay id;

public mainDisplay()
{

    String path;



      while (1==1) {

          try {

              FileInputStream roadMap = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\write.txt"); //path to the text file generated
              DataInputStream route = new DataInputStream(roadMap); //importing the data from the text file
              BufferedReader readMe = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(route));  
              pathOfspeed = readMe.readLine();
              //  id = new imageDisplay(path);

              Constants.getInstance().getBean().setPath(path);
              try {
                  Thread.sleep(40);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
              }




          } catch (Exception e) {                   
              System.err.println("error:" + e.getMessage());
          }

          System.out.println(Constants.getInstance().getBean().getPath());


      }



}
```

That is the code from the text file reader and the code that sets the Bean.

Here is the code from the bean class:

```
public class Paths implements java.io.Serializable{

    public String url;

    public Paths(){}

    public void setPath(String name){this.url=name;}

    public String getPath(){return url;}

}
```

I then have my constants class

```
public class Constants {
private static Constants instance;
private Paths bean;

private Constants() {
    bean=new Paths();
}

public static synchronized Constants getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new Constants();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Paths getBean(){
    return bean;
}

public Paths setBean(Paths p){
    bean = p;

    return p;
}
```

}

My problem then occurs when I try to get that Bean from another class:

```
String imageUrl=Constants.getInstance().getBean().getPath();

    public test () {

        System.out.println(imageUrl);

    }
```

I get null every single time.  The file reader needs to be constant as the line in the text file is changing about every minute and I need that passed to another class that uses it.

Could someone give me some suggestions as to what to do next?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your Constants class.

Every time you do:

```
Constants.Bean
```

it returns a newly created Path class which of course contains a null url variable which is returned to your getPath method.

You should use a Singleton for your Constants class.

Modify your Constants class:

```
public class Constants {
  private static Constants instance;
  private Paths bean;

  private Constants() {
     bean=new Paths();
  }

  public static synchronized Constants getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
      instance = new Constants();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public Paths getBean(){
    return bean;
  }

  public Paths setBean(Paths p){
    bean = p;
  }

}
```

Write to the Paths variable using:

```
Constants.getInstance().getBean().setPath("your path");
```

read the Paths variable;

```
Constants.getInstance().getBean().getPath();
```

Comment: I put a trivial error in the code...try now, the method name is of course getBean(). Aren't you using an IDE with some sort of code completion? If my answer solves your problem don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: The code now runs but I still get a null output from the test class with the new code.

Comment: Are you sure that path = readMe.readLine(); doesn't return null? Can you post your updated code for MainDisplay?

Comment: I have updated my original question with the new code for all classes

Comment: You're reading a variable and setting a different one...please have a look to:pathOfspeed = readMe.readLine(); //  id = new imageDisplay(path); Constants.getInstance().getBean().setPath(path);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44628/discussion-between-elbuild-and-user2352274)

Comment: YOu're reading the variable 'pathOfspeed' (pathOfspeed = readMe.readLine();) but you're setting the String 'path' in the singleton. That string is declared at the top and never initialized (so it's null).

Comment: That was a typo, it should read path, it still, however, produces a null value from the test class